# CSS transform-origin issue

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I'm working on a ghost floating [here](http://codepen.io/helenvholmes/pen/pecdI).

The issue I'm having is the transform-origin property. Right now the shadow (the ellipse on the bottom) seems to be expanding from the left to the right and then shrinking in that direction again. The behavior I *wanted* was for the shadow to expand and shrink from the middle - hence the transform-origin: 50% 50%;.

Here's the relevant code, although it helps to look at the Codepen:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -64.5px;
  margin-top: -85.5px;
}

.shadow {
  margin-left: 22px;
  animation: shrink 3s ease-out infinite;
  transform-origin: center center;
  ellipse {
    transform-origin: center center;
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    width: 20%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 27%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas, thank you so much! Really struggling with this for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got a solution for you.

What I did was use margin and width for the animation to keep it centered. I also gave the `p` tag that is containing the `svg` shadow a set width of the ghost to keep the shadow centered.

Here is the css I edited,

```
.shadowFrame {
 width: 130px;
}
.shadow {
  animation: shrink 3s ease-out infinite;
  transform-origin: center center;
  ellipse {
    transform-origin: center center;
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 20%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
}
```

Here is the [live link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tziIJ).

Comment: It's beautiful! Sort of mystifying why the transform-origin wasn't working, but this is really nice! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad you like it and you can adjust the size of the shadow to your liking. If this answered your question you can mark it as the accepted answer, best of luck. :] It's not working how you expect it to since the width is growing from small to larger. The shadow is resting `22px` in from the p tag. When it grows in width the point it is resting on is not changing, instead it is only growing to the right since it's left point is fixed.

Comment: You also should just add margin: 0 auto; on the .shadow class and then remove the margin from the key frames.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand what's going on a little better. I'll make those changes!

Comment: No problem! It also doesn't seem to work with `margin: 0 auto;` which is a wee bit odd. Oh, duh, it doesn't have a fixed width on the shadow in the css is why it doesn't work, only in the keyframes! :] Best of luck none the less! :]